# java getResourceAsStream: InputStream is empty

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, classpath, executable-jar

I have a problem with loading resources after I exported my application as a runnable jar.

The scenario is the following:

I have a resource folder that is in the class path. Inside the resource folder there is another folder with text several files representing database queries. My first solution to get the directory was the following:

```
URI queryResource = this.getClass().getResource("/queries/").toURI();
File queryDir = new File(queryResource);
```

This worked as expected while I was testing the code inside eclipse. As soon as I exported the application into a runnable char I got `NullPointerExceptions`. A research into the problem yielded a solution that used `getResourceAsStream`rather than the `getResource` method.

I tested this first on a few XML files that I use for configuration purposes. So I used:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(/config/xml/configFile.xml);
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
parser.parse(in, this);
```

This solution works for the configuration files in eclipse and in the exported jar. To load the query files I wrote a small utility method to use the `InputStream` to create a temporary directory where I copy the query files into. The method looks like this:

```
public static URI createDirectory(Class<?> resourceClass, String directory) throws IOException {

    //create temp dir to store the files
    File tempDir = FileUtility.createTempDir();

    InputStream in = resourceClass.getResourceAsStream(directory));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String readLine = null;

    while((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

         InputStream inputFileStream = resourceClass.getResourceAsStream(resource + readLine);
         File tempFile = new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + readLine);
         tempFile.createNewFile();
         tempFile.deleteOnExit();

         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
         IOUtils.copy(inputFileStream, fos);
    }

    return tempDir.toUri();
}
```

Now from there I use my regular code to read the files:

```
URI queryResource = createDirectory(this.getClass, "/queries/");
queryDir = new File(queryResource);
```

This again works fine while running the application in eclipse. In the exported jar however the first `InputStream` in the `createDirectory`method is empty. The stream is not `null` it is instantiated but has no content.

Does anyone has an idea what is wrong? Please let me know.

Greetings

PS: the machine with the IDE has no access to the web at the moment so I typed this by hand. There might be some mistakes. The code I wrote doesn't have any syntax errors. If you find any in the code in this post they are my mistake.